# Angular, define global variable over components for navigation

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I have the following navigation link:

```
<a (click)="mylink(someLink)">SomeLink</a>
```

Which belongs to:

```
<div #someLink class="someLink active">
 Container Content
</div>
```

But the relative TypeScript code works only local in the same compoment. But I want  outsource the links in an own navigation component and another component for the content.

```
mylink(page: any, event: any) {
    page.classList.add('active'); // show the 'WebContainer SomeLink'
}
```

How can I realise this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular Routing for this. See: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5

When generating your app, just say "Yes" to Routing.
In your navigation component build a link like the following:

```
<a [routerLink]="['yourcomponent']" ">SomeLink</a>
```

Hint: Do not use a href tag !!!

In app.modules.ts check for:

```
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
```

In app-routing.modules.ts import **all** clickable components:

```
import { YourComponent } from './yourcomponent/yourcomponent.component';
```

and add your routes (e.g. links) in the same file like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: YourStartComponent },
  { path: 'yourcomponent', component: YourComponent },
];
```